# Make a {position:sticky; top:0} element's bottom stay within the viewport (without JS)

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, sticky, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a dashboard frame (in Bootstrap 5, but I don't think it makes any difference) that works like in these two pictures:

1. [image: browser scrolled top]
2. [image: browser scrolled middle]

This is basically my current situation:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="pretoolbar">pretoolbar (non-essential information, to be hidden when scrolling)
    </div>
    <div class="sticky-toolbar"> sticky toolbar</div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="sidebar col-3">
        [tall sidebar content]
      </div>
      <main class="col-9">
        [also tall content]
      </main>
    </div>
  <body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.pretoolbar{
    background-color: #555;
    color:white;
    height:32px;
}
.sticky-toolbar{
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    height:56px;
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
}
.sidebar{
    background-color: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 56px;
    overflow: hidden auto;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
    height: 100%;
}
```

I'm trying several approaches but it doesn't seem working. What I'm trying is of course `position: sticky` on the main sticky toolbar and on the sidebar. But due to the different available vertical space (scrolled-top vs scrolled-middle), after declaring a height for the sidebar (`calc(100vh - 56px)`, 56px is the height of the toolbar) it results in the bottom part of the sidebar and its scrollbar to fall out of the viewport bottom. I'm considering flexbox, `position:fixed`, `position:absolute`... cannot find a way to get it through.

I also discovered a strange behavior (in Chrome at least) when you place a `position:sticky` inside a `position:fixed`

My goal would be to avoid JavaScript, I basically need a sidebar that changes its height after the sticky-state of the toolbar and sticky searchbox. (Or, to say it in other words, the top-edge of the sidebar should behave like `position:sticky` while the bottom-edge should behave like `position:fixed;bottom:0`).

Can you think of a way of achieving this without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if I am understanding your situation. First I would suggest getting rid off of the *pre-toolbar bar. Otherwise, the desired behavior is impossible without js. And since you mentioned the information there is not essential, you can put it anywhere.

However, if you still want it to be on top, then sticky of position fixed the toolbar and the sidebar. Do not use `calc()` It is better to use height 100vh and put it behind the toolbar so it seems to be shorter. Then, place a pre-toolbar on top (z-index) of your toolbar and animated it to disappear after some seconds.

Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/oscontrerasn/pen/WNpxJwV

Comment: Ok, yes you got the situation right, and thank you for your reply. But I need that pre-toolbar to be visible when scrolled top. It's not essential information so there's no need to keep it on the sticky toolbar while you're scrolling down the page, but I need it to be there when scrolling all top (an absolute positioned div disappearing after a small time is not a viable solution for my case).

Comment: Please include your code in the answer itself. When that codepen link dies, the answer will lose utility.